# How to bypass Xcode code signing certificate

Tags: ios, code-signing, xcode10.3

[image: enter link description here]I am trying to test a third party iOS app. But the Web-driver Agent is asking for code signing. Is there a way, I can bypass that in Xcode 10.3.

Comment: If you just need to run it in the simulator you can simply disable the codesigning, just go to Build Settings and clear the value for the **Code Signing identity**.

Comment: I actually have to run it on a real device. I have been trying to disable code signing but so far, I am unable to do it.

Comment: You can't disable code signing if you want to run on a real device. Try changing the appid to one that belongs to your developer account.

Comment: hmm, I am working on a third party app that was not develop through Xcode. When I change the WebDriver Agent bundle Id to my app ID. It takes my developer profile, but then instead of opening my app. It converts my app to an Xcode generated project app called integration app.